# problem installing mathpix snip

Tags: linux, latex, snap

I'm trying to install mathpix snip to convert an equation from a pdf to LaTeX code following the instructions on the website

https://mathpix.com/docs/snip/linux-overview

and when I try to run the command: `sudo snap install mathpix-snipping-tool`

I get the following error:

> snap "mathpix-snipping-tool" not found.

I don't know what can I do to install it correctly.
I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: Same thing. Strange...

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution to this problem. I emailed support@mathpix and they got back to me with this

download file from this URL https://download.mathpix.com/linux/Mathpix_Snipping_Tool-x86_64.v03.00.0065.AppImage

Here are detailed steps:

1    Open your terminal. And execute the following

2    cd ~/Downloads

3    wget https://download.mathpix.com/linux/Mathpix_Snipping_Tool-x86_64.v03.00.0065.AppImage -O Mathpix_Snipping_Tool.AppImage

4    chmod 777 ./Mathpix_Snipping_Tool.AppImage

5    ./Mathpix_Snipping_Tool.AppImage

This was an immediate fix for me. Each time you want to use it though you need to open terminal change directory to download and entire line 5 in the command prompt.

Comment: It worked! Thanks!